# Is $T: V \rightarrow V$ s.t. $T(x,y,z) = (y,z,x)$ abuse of notation if $V \leq \mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

My math professor has asked me to do the following:

> Let $V = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x + y + z = 0\}$. Let $\alpha = \{(1, 0, -1), (0, 1, -1)\}$ and $\beta = \{(1, 1, -2), (1, -1, 0)\}$ be ordered bases for $V$. Let $T: V\rightarrow V$ be the linear transformation defined by $T(x,y,z) = (y, z, x)$. Calculate $[T]_\alpha^\beta$.

I'm having a hard time understanding why it is correct to write $T(x,y,z) = (y,z,x)$ if $T$ maps to and from a two-dimensional space. In particular, the very definition of $T$ seems to imply to me that we are thinking of $T$ as an operator on $\mathbb{R}^3$, using the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$. My suspicion is that this is a slight abuse of notation, i.e. that by writing basis $\alpha$ in coordinate form, i.e. $\alpha = \{(1, 0, -1), (0, 1, -1)\}$, we are actually implying that there is a "hidden" transformation $A: V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ that first "prepares" vectors in $V$ by sending them to $\mathbb{R}^3$ so that $T$, which is actually an operator on $\mathbb{R}^3$, knows what to do with these vectors. In fact, if $B: V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ similarly writes the $\beta$ vectors in coordinate form, then I believe I can get the desired result essentially by taking the product $[T]_\alpha^\beta = [B]^{-1} [T] [A]$, where I'm using the left-inverse of $[B]$.

I guess in short, is writing $T(x,y,z) = (y,z,x)$ technically a light abuse of notation?

Comment: I guess it isn't an abuse of notation. $\mathbb{R}^3$ is the space of triples of real numbers - even when we ommit the vector space structure. So this $T$ can be defined regardless of base coordinates, just by permuting the numbers in the triple.

Comment: Specifying a base in a finite dimension vector space is the same as specifying an isomorphism between this space and some $\mathbb{R}^n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** $T$ is the linear transformation of $\Bbb R^3$ whose matrix is $\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\0&0&1\\1&0&0\end{pmatrix}$ *restricted* to $V$.

Since $V$ is *invariant* under $T$, that is, $T(V)\subseteq V$, this makes sense.

Comment: This makes sense, and thank you. My thought here is that any basis of $V$ will be a double, like $\alpha = \{a, b\}$, which we then map into a coordinate representation in $\mathbb{R}^3$, which $T$ then transforms, and we then map the result back into $V$ using some other transformation. So the solution can be found by multiplying three matrices. My prof said that we don't need to do all that, and it's just much simpler, and plug and chug. But my contention basically is: Any other method is *essentially* doing all that, and just hiding the underlying mechanics. Is that not correct?

Comment: While $V$ is two-dimensional, and so isomorphic to $\Bbb R^2$, I think your prof has a point, because of the way $V$ is a plane in $\Bbb R^3$.

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely not abuse of notation. You have a map $T:V\to V$ and $V\subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ so it takes triples to triples.

The space $\mathbb{R}^3$ has many two dimensional subspaces (geometrically all planes through the origin).

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! It seems to me that if $\alpha = \{(1, 0, -1), (0, 1, -1)\}$ and I want to map $Tv$, where $v = 2(1, 0 ,-1) + 3(0, 1, -1) = (2, 3, -1)$, then literally the first thing I've done is I've taken my vector $v$ and rewritten it in the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$. So that's the abuse of notation: If we write $\alpha = \{(1, 0, -1), (0, 1, -1)\}$, then aren't we implicitly just transforming the vectors of $\alpha$, whatever they are, by rewriting those vectors in the standard basis on $\mathbb{R}^3$?